# How to display an extra colum in my SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, grafana

I have a table called **treeview** with a **id, name, assettype** and **parent**.

I have another table which is called **events** with a **id** and **treeid**.

a treeview instance can have events and then treeview.id = events.treeid.

I made a query to show all the events and show the treeid, sensor name and parent.
But I want to show the machine name as well.

The problem is that my "machine" name and "sensor" name are in the same column but machine names have assettype = 2 and sensor names have assettype = 3 or 4.

For example in the first row the "Motor NDE Vertical" (sensor) has parent "1191" which is "Sidewinch PS" (machine) but it's not showing up.

I guess I need to implement the "WHERE assettype = ..." somewhere but I can't find where.

Can anyone help me with this please?

**This is my query:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT(e.treeid), t.name as "sensor", t.parent, (SELECT name FROM treeview WHERE parent = id) as "machine"
FROM events e, treeview t
WHERE e.treeid = t.id
ORDER BY treeid
```

**And this is my result is Grafana:**
[image]

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be a big help.

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.treeid, t.name as "sensor", t.parent, p.name as "machine"
FROM events e
INNER JOIN treeview t ON e.treeid = t.id AND  t.assettype IN (3, 4)
INNER JOIN treeview p ON p.id=t.parent AND p.assettype=2
ORDER BY e.treeid
```

The trick is to join 2 times the `treeview` table and to specify their `assettype` in the `ON` clause :

1. To get the sensors
2. To get the machines that are parents of those sensors

I can hardly be more accurate with the information in your question

Comment: THIS WORKS.
THANK YOU VERY MUCH!
I added `WHERE e.treeid = t.id` like in my previous query.

Comment: @Thethiefer [caps on] YOU ARE WELCOME. [caps off]

Comment: in theory you dont need that WHERE, its in the ON clause